# Hibernate inheritance implementation issue

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, nhibernate-inheritance

I want to write one hbm file.

My class hierarchy is

```
BaseClassOne{
private long id;
...getters and setters....
}

ClassA extends BaseClassOne{
other private members;
...getters and setters....
}

classB extends BaseClassOne{
other private members;
...getters and setters....
}
```

now,

I am writing another classsay ClassMain which will have object type of ClassA  OR classB depending on some criteria(say column type in ClassMain)

in my model class i have written

```
..other private members ....

private BaseClassOne objectAtRuntime;


...getters setters.....
```

Now, Please tell me in hbm files how to implement this...???

or tell me other alternatives to implement the same.

Answer (score 0):

this is what `<any>` mapping is for. [See here for a blogpost describing how to map it in xml](http://ayende.com/blog/3966/nhibernate-mapping-any). Despite it being written for NHibernate it should be the same for hibernate